# Spring MVC localization in controller class is not working

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, localization

I created a Spring MVC project and tried to change to session locale within an controller class.

So, here are the most important files from my project:

**`applicationContext.xml` (only partly..):**

```
  <context:component-scan base-package="de.my.packages.controller" />

  <context:annotation-config />

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/springMessages" />
    </bean>

<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="de" />
</bean>
```

JSP file ( only partly..)

```
<spring:message code="test.abc" />
```

springMessages.properties

```
test.abc=This is a testText.
```

springMessages_de.properties

```
test.abc=Das ist ein TestText.
```

Controller-class

```
@Controller
public class InitController {

    @Autowired
    private SessionLocaleResolver localeResolver;

    @RequestMapping("/testPage")
    public String showLogin( HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
        localeResolver.setLocale(request, response, Locale.ENGLISH);
        return ("testPage");
    }
}
```

So - when I call

```
http://localhost:8080/myContext/testPage
```

the JSP will be called and displayed. But although I changed the language in the controller to English , the displayed text is German.
I did not add a `localChangeInterceptor` class, because my target is not to change the language via URL.

Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Try renaming your first file to `springMessages_en.properties`.

Comment: I can't believe this - that's it! After renaming it's working - but I don't understand why. I thought, that it is not necessary to put "_en" on the filename of a property file, because doing not is the same! That is what I've red somewhere. Isn't that right?
Btw: thank you so much!

Comment: Not putting anything makes it the *default*. For most of the authors you've read, that means English, but not for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`springMessages.properties` is the default message resource bundle. To use English resource bundle you should copy this file to `springMessages_en.properties`. Because you set locale with

```
localeResolver.setLocale(request, response, Locale.ENGLISH);
```

the resource bundle is used `springMessages_en.properties`.